# Run Code From Joomla Article

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, joomla-3.5

Is it possible to run `JQuery` or `JavaScript` in a Joomla Article?

I ask because I have tried just about every possible option I see on forums/interwebs and the data does not display as I desire.

Comment: https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep you can totally run javascript in a Joomla article (I presume you mean can I insert javascript into the html/code view of the Joomla editor and this can run on page load when an article is viewed). BUT - if you are using an editor like JCE Editor then javascript will be stripped by default and you will need to change the editor profile to allow javascript.  Can you more succinctly describe your issue if it is something else or if I am misinterpreting?